# How to get javascript 'value' property for custom textbox control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, custom-controls

I created one custom control which contains TextBox as a child control (and contains some other controls also). After this I placed this control in a Page and I'm trying to get TextBox value(i.e text) through javascript. But I'm unable to get 'value' property directly.

**Custom Control code:**

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 

namespace AjaxServerControlDevelopment 
{ 
    public class MyTextBox: CompositeControl 
    { 
        /// <summary> 
        /// TextBox reference variable 
        /// </summary> 
        public TextBox objTextBox; 


        /// <summary> 
        /// The TextChanged event 
        /// </summary> 
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1009:DeclareEventHandlersCorrectly")] 
        public event EventHandler TextChanged; 

        /// <summary> 
        /// The ButtonClick event 
        /// </summary> 
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1009:DeclareEventHandlersCorrectly")] 
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ButtonClick; 


            #region Class constructors 


    /// <summary> 
    /// Default constructor 
    /// </summary> 
    public MyTextBox() 
    { 
        ////Instantiates the wrapped control 

        objTextBox = new TextBox(); 

        objTextBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(objTextBox_TextChanged); 


    } 
        #endregion 

    void objTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (TextChanged != null) 
        { 
            TextChanged(this, e); 
        } 
    } 


    #region Property:Text 
    /// <summary> 
    ///       Gets or sets the Text of TngTextBox 
    /// Returns: 
    ///     A System.String Object. The default value is System.Null 
    /// </summary> 
    public string Text 
    { 

        get 
        { 

                return objTextBox.Text; 

        } 

        set 
        { 

                objTextBox.Text = value; 

        } 


    } 
    #endregion 

      #region ChildControls 
    /// <summary> 
    /// Allows us to attach child controls to our composite control 
    /// </summary> 
    protected override void CreateChildControls() 
    { 
        Controls.Clear(); 
        this.Controls.Add(objTextBox); 
        base.CreateChildControls(); 
    } 
      #endregion 
}
```

**ControlDemo Page Code:**

```
<head runat="server"> 
<title></title> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function met1() { 
        var objTextBox = document.getElementById('<%=MyTextBox1.ClientID %>'); 
        //alert(objTextBox.children[0].value); 
        alert(objTextBox.value); 
    } 
</script>
```

```
    <cc1:MyTextBox ID="MyTextBox1" runat="server" /> 
    <br /> 

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="met1();" runat="server" Text="Button" /> 

</form>
```

In ViewSource of the DemoPage, this control is rendering as a `Span Element` inside `input Element`

So I'm getting TextBox value if I write like this

```
document.getElementById('<%=MyTextBox1.ClientID%>').children[0].value
```

How to expose 'value' property like this:  document.getElementById('<%=MyTextBox1.CleintID%>').value?

Comment: I think provided snippet is not correct or is not complete. I don't see where you have a MyTextBox1 inserted in your page markup.

Comment: Yes Tengiz, MyTextBox1 control placed in the markup page. And it looks like this                                       <cc1:MyTextBox ID="MyTextBox1" runat="server" /> <br /> <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="met1();" runat="server" Text="Button" />

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is you are trying to get a value of `MyTextBox1` which is not a textbox in fact, so it does not have a value.

What to do instead:

**Version 1** - change your script to be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function met1() { 
        alert('<%=MyTextBox1.Text %>'); 
    } 
</script>
```

and this is quite enough to have a text in javascript.

**Version 2** - add a property to your TextBox class like this:

```
public TextBox ObjTextBox
{
    get { return objTextBox; }
}
```

then change your script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function met1() { 
        var objTextBox = document.getElementById('<%=MyTextBox1.ObjTextBox.ClientID %>'); 
        alert(objTextBox.value); 
    } 
</script>
```

this should also work.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Tengiz, Thanks for your reply. I want to simulate the same behaviuor of normal TextBox to my control-user.My control-user should not think that this is a composite control. Two approches you suggested will work fine. However I have to write like document.getElementById('<%=MyTextBox1.**ObjTextBox**.ClientID %>');  When a compiste control renders, our child controls will be wrapped by SPAN element by-default.Is there any way when text entered in MyTextBox1 has to assign this text to 'value' attribute of wrapped SPAN element.('value' attribute added by writer. addAttribute() in Render method

Comment: No, that is incorrect to have value attribute for span. I know that works for some browsers (like IE), but it does not for others (like Mozilla). I guess in that case you will need to create your own textbox not as a composite, but instead as a full-fledged textbox control from scratch. In general, value attribute has sense only for input controls, like textbox, button, textarea...

Comment: Hi Tengiz, Thank you for reply. I used the version 2 what you have suggested. Its working well in normal asp.net page. But if I put 'MytextBox' and 'button' in a updatePanel, javascript function is working first time if I click the button. [i.e var objTextBox = document.getElementById('<%=MyTextBox1.ObjTextBox.ClientID %>'); alert(objTextBox.value); --- is giving the whatever I entered in the MyTextBox].If I click second time button its throwing javascript exception "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required" (this error is comming at the line --[ alert(objTextBox.value);]).Any idea?

Comment: This should be related somehow to the updatePanel. What does happen with update panel when you click the button?

Comment: As I'm putting both of these (MyTextBox and Button) in updatepanel, when I click button, only that portion (these two controls) of page will go to server(i.e partial postback will happen). But really I did not understand why document.getElementById('myclientid') is becomming null from second click onwards.

Comment: Gotcha! it is because you are doing the partial post-back, after which either clientID changes or something else becomes indeterministic. And what if you remove the updatePanel? if it contains only these two controls, then you should not need to make a postback.

Comment: Hi Tengiz, If I don't put in Update panel then its working absolutly fine. Problem when put both of these in updatePangel only. And I cheked, clienID is not changing before first click and after click of the button. And my control-user is using all these controls in updatepanel. Any other way to expose 'value' property?

Comment: Just remove update panel if you don't need that. No other suggestions, sorry.